# Can resources be set from a variable?

Tags: android, resources

I'm writing a case statement to launch and xml parser activity and want to set a different inputstream based on what the user clicks, can I set the inputstream from a variable?

Here's the inputstream:

```
InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.myxmlfile);
```

I've tried setting a string with `getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.myxmlfile)` and that didn't work, I also tried setting the xml file as a string and that didn't work. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a string. It should be declared integer.

```
int[] xmlfile = { R.raw.xml1, R.raw.xml2 };
getResources().openRawResource(xmlfile[0]);
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you so much! I can't vote the answer up since I'm new to the forum, but this IS the answer to my question.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried to move the xml file into `assets folder` and then do

`InputStream inputStream = context.getAssets().open(FILE_NAME);`  ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int r = R.raw.myxmlfile;
InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(r);
```